# Issues with window.location.assign

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, window.location

I'm trying to create a form that checks the input, sees if it is correct, and then loads a new webpage if it is, but my code isn't working, new page is not loaded on even if input is correct. I'm using `window.location.assign` to try to accomplish that.

Here's the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> INDEX </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "this") {
            window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");  
        }   else {
                alert("Try again");
                return false;

            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="center">
        <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp"
        onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

        <p> type "this" </p> 
        <input type="text" name="fname">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please define "isn't working".

Comment: New page is not loaded on even if input is correct. It validates properly - I can get the if statement to do other things, just not window.location.assign

Comment: You can't change location while browser is pending for a server call. Cancel the default action of the submit event before trying to change `location`. Also, the value of a textbox is never `null`, it's always a string, an empty string, if nothing was entered.

Answer (score 0):

there is no issue with window.location.assign ,there is issue with your code ,if u really want widow.location.assign to work try this-

```
<div id="center">
    <form name="myForm" 
    onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    <p> type "this" </p> 
    <input type="text" name="fname">

    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This does't make any difference. And there is an issue when changing `location` while browser is pending for server call.

Comment: Can u tell me what are u inputting in your text box,as it is working absolutely fine for me

Comment: That validation aspect of the code is working fine for me. And it checks to see if the text inputted is the word "this".